# Smaller link font size inside h2 tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a link with normal `font-size` inside `h2` tag which is going to be pulled to the right side

How could I have different `font-size` without going to the new line?

I want this to be all in the same line...whatever I put inside the link it goes to the new line

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2 class="title-bg acenter">title
      <a class="heading pull-right" href="#">
              pull right link title
      </a>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try use `small`, which set `font-size` to `65%` in bootstrap (you probably will need to style the `small` tag, color wise)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>With small</h1>
<h2 class="title-bg acenter">title
     <a class="heading pull-right" href="#">
         <small> pull right link title</small>
     </a>
</h2>
<hr />
<h1>Without small</h1>
<h2 class="title-bg acenter">title
     <a class="heading pull-right" href="#">
         pull right link title
     </a>
</h2>
```

Comment: Or you could just add `style="font-size: small;"` to the `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this:

```
<h2 class="title-bg acenter">title
     <a class="heading pull-right sm_font" href="#">
          pull right link title
     </a>
</h2>
```

CSS:

```
a.sm_font{font-size:12px}
```